# Add anchor tags dynamically to a div when page load in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 divs that all have the same css class, as follows:

```
/*div 1 */
<div class="oxilab-flip-box-col-5 oxilab-flip-box-padding-1" >
    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-body-1 oxilab-flip-box-body-1-1">
        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-body-absulote">
            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-flip oxilab-flip-box-flip-left-to-right">
                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-style-data easing_easeInOutCirc">
                    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-style">
                        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-front">
                            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-1">
                                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-1-data">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back">
                            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back-1">
                                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back-1-data">
                                    <div class="oxilab-heading" googl="true">
                                        heading                                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="oxilab-info">
                                        some text                                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="http://test.com" target="">
                                        <span class="oxilab-button">
                                            <span class="oxilab-button-data">
                                            enter                                                                    
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>

/*div 2 */
<div class="oxilab-flip-box-col-5 oxilab-flip-box-padding-1" >
    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-body-1 oxilab-flip-box-body-1-1">
        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-body-absulote">
            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-flip oxilab-flip-box-flip-left-to-right">
                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-style-data easing_easeInOutCirc">
                    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-style">
                        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-front">
                            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-1">
                                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-1-data">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back">
                            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back-1">
                                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back-1-data">
                                    <div class="oxilab-heading" googl="true">
                                        heading                                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="oxilab-info">
                                        some text                                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="http://example.com" target="">
                                        <span class="oxilab-button">
                                            <span class="oxilab-button-data">
                                            enter                                                                    
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

As you can see, both main divs have `oxilab-flip-box-col-5` class and each has an ahref tag, now I want all the div components to be linked when the page is loaded, as follows:

```
/*div 1 */
<a href="http://test.com" target="">
    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-col-5 oxilab-flip-box-padding-1" >
    .
    .
    .   
    </div>
</a>

/*div 2 */
<a href="http://example.com" target="">
    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-col-5 oxilab-flip-box-padding-1" >
    .
    .
    .   
    </div>
</a>
```

I was able to write this code with JavaScript, but unfortunately, the code I wrote does not work.

```
var fisrtdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"http://test.com");
aTag.innerText = "some text";
fisrtdiv.appendChild(aTag);

var seconddiv = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"http://example.com");
aTag.innerText = "some text";
seconddiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

Any idea how I can do this and link each div separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here You Go:**

```
var first_div = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5")[0];
var parent1 = first_div.parentNode;
var a_tag1 = document.createElement('a');

parent1.replaceChild(a_tag1, first_div)
a_tag1.appendChild(first_div)
a_tag1.setAttribute('href',"http://example.com");

/////////

var second_div = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5")[1];
var parent2 = second_div.parentNode;
var a_tag2 = document.createElement('a');

parent2.replaceChild(a_tag2, second_div)
a_tag2.appendChild(second_div)
a_tag2.setAttribute('href',"http://example.com");
```

Comment: Thank you for your correct answer, if I want the href value for each div to be selected automatically and I don't have to enter each domain manually (for times when the number of divs becomes too large), do you have any ideas?

Comment: Most welcome! If you want all the div elements to be wrapped with an anchor of the same href value, then simply iterate over them with a loop from 0 to document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5").length

Comment: I apologize, I did not understand, can you please edit your answer

Comment: Do you want all anchors to have the same href link? Or each one has a distinct one?

Comment: As you can see in the code, each div has a separate a tag with its own href address, and I want the script to select the href for each div and do the linking.

Comment: Can you please guide me?

Comment: `var links = ['http://example1.com','http://example2.com','http://example3.com','http://example4.com'];
        for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5").length;i++){
            var div = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5")[i];
            var parent = div.parentNode;
            var a_tag = document.createElement('a');
    
            parent.replaceChild(a_tag, div)
            a_tag.appendChild(div)
            a_tag.setAttribute('href',links[i]);
        }`

Comment: make sure you have your links in the links array.

Comment: also make sure you have the number of links equal to the number of the div elements, if you have less links and don't want all the div to be hyperlinked, then use `links.length` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5").length` in the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there a way for the script itself to read the value of each href and link the div to it, so that we don't need to change the content of the script every time the href changes?

Comment: where should the script get the links from?

Comment: from the inner a tag of each div

Comment: so initially each div contains an anchor tag with a link?

Comment: yes sir, of course

Comment: sorry for the late response, what you should do in this case is add a class to the inner anchor tags for example : class="anchor"
in this case in the for loop in the above code in the comments, use a_tag.setAttribute('href',document.getElementsByClassName("anchor")[i])

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` return an `HTMLCollection` of elements.

Change your code to:

```
var fisrtdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5")[0];
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"http://test.com");
aTag.innerText = "some text";
fisrtdiv.appendChild(aTag);

var seconddiv = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5")[1];
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"http://example.com");
aTag.innerText = "some text";
seconddiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

Comment: When I use your code, the output looks like this: `    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-col-5 oxilab-flip-box-padding-1" >
    .
    .
    .   
<a href="http://example.com" googl="true">some text</a></div>` And the DIV is not linked

Comment: Do you sure that there is only two div by that classname?

Comment: No, on the page I tested the script, there are 15 divs with that class

Comment: can’t you just add a class to select by?

Comment: And explain your question more clearly will let us understand faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). You can see that you do 2 times the same thing. What if you need to do it 100 times? Then your code will get messy quickly.

You'll see 2 solutions in my code: the ugly way (not DRY) and the cleaner way (DRY). There's a even cleaner way but let's start with this ;)

```js
    /*THE UGLY WAY*/
   /*
    var fisrtdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5")[0];
    var first_link = document.createElement('a');
    first_link.setAttribute('href',"http://test.com");
    first_link.innerText = "some text1";
    first_link.append(fisrtdiv);

    document.body.append(first_link);

    //we take again at index 0 because before this line we changed the position of the flip boxes
    var seconddiv = document.getElementsByClassName("oxilab-flip-box-col-5")[0];
    var second_link = document.createElement('a');
    second_link.setAttribute('href',"http://example.com");
    second_link.innerText = "some text2";
    second_link.append(seconddiv);

    document.body.append(second_link);
    */

    /*CLEANER WAY*/
    var
      list_of_flip_boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".oxilab-flip-box-col-5"),
      list_of_links = [
        {
          text : "some text 1",
          href : "http://test.com"
        },
        {
          text : "some text 2",
          href : "http://example.com"
        },
      ];

    list_of_flip_boxes.forEach(function(flip_box, index){
      var
        link_element = document.createElement("a"),
        link_data = list_of_links[index];

      link_element.setAttribute('href', link_data.href);
      link_element.innerText = link_data.text;

      link_element.append(flip_box);

      document.body.append(link_element);
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
</head>

<body>

<div class="oxilab-flip-box-col-5 oxilab-flip-box-padding-1" >
    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-body-1 oxilab-flip-box-body-1-1">
        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-body-absulote">
            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-flip oxilab-flip-box-flip-left-to-right">
                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-style-data easing_easeInOutCirc">
                    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-style">
                        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-front">
                            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-1">
                                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-1-data">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back">
                            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back-1">
                                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back-1-data">
                                    <div class="oxilab-heading" googl="true">
                                        heading                                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="oxilab-info">
                                        some text                                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="http://test.com" target="">
                                        <span class="oxilab-button">
                                            <span class="oxilab-button-data">
                                            enter                                                                    
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>


<div class="oxilab-flip-box-col-5 oxilab-flip-box-padding-1" >
    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-body-1 oxilab-flip-box-body-1-1">
        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-body-absulote">
            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-flip oxilab-flip-box-flip-left-to-right">
                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-style-data easing_easeInOutCirc">
                    <div class="oxilab-flip-box-style">
                        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-front">
                            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-1">
                                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-1-data">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back">
                            <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back-1">
                                <div class="oxilab-flip-box-back-1-data">
                                    <div class="oxilab-heading" googl="true">
                                        heading                                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="oxilab-info">
                                        some text                                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="http://example.com" target="">
                                        <span class="oxilab-button">
                                            <span class="oxilab-button-data">
                                            enter                                                                    
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
  
</body>

</html>
```